# Firebase database secure without firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have an app published on the play store, I want to implement firebase in the app.

I have read all the documentation and I have two doubts:

1. If someone use apk decompiler with my app and get the googleservices.json, they can do whatever they want with the database?
2. It is possible that my database is secure without having the user logged-in?

I would appreciate any help

Comment: These are contradictory requirements:  Make my database secure but do not enforce any security. Either you require them to authenticate or you allow world write access to the data. See also [Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth), which could be what you're looking for, and the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), which this question is. Also, see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The fact that someone can read your *googleservices.json* doesn't involve security holes. If you configured your Firebase project correctly, you will notice that in the "**Project Settings**" panel there is a SHA-1 signature to add. If you add the signature of your **debug/production keystore**, only apps with the specific signature con use the data of googleservices.json to communicate with your Firebase platform. (If you decide to not provide a SHA-1, Google will use something else as identification mechanism as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#android-sha1))
2. This question is not very clear. Your database is safe everytime. If your user is not logged in, probably he will not able to communicate with the database. Remember that a user should only be able to see it's own data, so if your app logic is correct a logged user shouldn't be able to see other peoples sensitive data. Moreover remember to not change the database/storage connection rules in the "**Rules**" panel like in the image below to prevent unauthorized operations:[image: rules panel in Firebase console]

Comment: Let's say that I have the googleservices.json of an app, I create a project, add the file, put the same app id,etc.I will be able to do whatever I want with the database, right?

Comment: No, because your app will not be signed with the same SHA-1 of the original Firebase project. You can imagine the SHA-1 as the private key, which only the Firebase project owner knows. When you use a Firebase functionality which requires authentication, you won't be able to complete it because you have only the public key (inside the googleservices.json file) but not the private key, so the server will not authorize you to proceed (if configured correctly)

Comment: I got it, and what if while I was setting up the project I didn't add the SHA-1?I will do it now anyway

Comment: If you don't add the SHA-1, Firebase probably will fallback with some other type of identification mechanisms (i don't know which ones sincerely). But as you can read here: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#android-sha1 if you wanna use some specific tools you must add the SHA-1 certificate(s)

Comment: @MatPag can you please have a look to my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55120747/how-to-protect-firebase-data-from-being-accessed-out-side-the-app