# How to protect firebase data from being accessed out side the app?

Tags: firebase

I have an video streaming android app. Firebase project contains videos links and meta. I have implemented authentication and firebase database rules so that only authenticated users can access those videos.

Still someone is able to access the links and downloading videos to upload on youtube.

So my question is how to completely stop users from accessing my json outside the app. I have limited the read operation only to authenticated users.

Is it possible for anyone to signup to my project using command line and then accessing the data?

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42101663/3340665 (Question 1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be this:

1. Authenticated users get the link to your video
2. They download it while authenticated
3. They do what they want with the video (and they don't need to be authenticated again)

There are no easy solutions to this common problem.

You should encrypt the streaming data passed between the server and client using technologies like [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) and [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) which is the one Netflix uses in their website to send data to a TV.

> You probably need to understand how much big is your business and if it's worth
>   proceeding in this direction implementing the necessary part.

Useful links:

- [Google encrypt/decrypt media packager](https://github.com/google/shaka-packager)
- [A guide on how to implement DRM content in exo player](https://medium.com/@takusemba/play-your-own-drm-content-on-exoplayer-e8ed73d5864c)
- [DRM used by Netflix and others on their Website](https://www.widevine.com/solutions)

Comment: that is android app built using nativescript. its not  browser based web app so how is the user able to access the link? I m have also implemented some common methods like webpack and other techniques to scramble the app code to prevent any reverse engineering.

Comment: Mmm ok, maybe they simply screen record your videos?

Comment: Actually that guy contacted me for some favour, he sent me my complete database json and threatened me to harm the app functionality if i dont do what he is saying.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think if you store parte of the Firebase database in the application, using command line or android studio you can extract the database.

Comment: Thats also not the case. App is very basic I am not even using firebase offline feature.